RabbitMQ fails to start with `{error,not_json}` after upgrade to 3.11
After upgrading our rabbitmq to v3.11 it fails to start with the following message:

Error during startup: {error,not_json}

It is the same configuration as exported from 3.10, loaded via an environment variable that overwrites the definitions.json file in a custom init script (#!/bin/sh).
Our docker image is based on the official rabbitmq docker images with some minor additions.

It turns out that the underlying JSON parser was changed in v3.11. It is more performant but also more strict/sensitive. As per this discussion it's important to assert that the definitions.json file does not contain a BOM and uses LF for newlines and not CRLF.
In our case the problem was completely different, our definitions contain values with escaped regexes e.g. "pattern": ".+\\.response\\.queue". When echoing (echo $MQ_DEFINITIONS > definitions.json), echo was converting double backslash \\ to single backslash \ and a single backslash followed by . is actually invalid json. The solution in our case was to use printf "%s" $MQ_DEFINITIONS instead. This will depend on the platform and shell used.
